# HUOIN 430P под линуксом

Tags: linux, input

Подключал планшет по этой инструкции https://www.davidrevoy.com/article331/setup-huion-giano-wh1409-tablet-on-linux-mint-18-1-ubuntu-16-04
Частично удалось. Планшет работает, чувствительность есть на пере две кнопки работает (левая и средняя кнопка мыши), но 4 тех, что на самом планшете — нет.
В `xlist` планшет присутствует, `xsetwacom --list devices` не выводит ничего,
в `lsusb` устройство выводится но без имени (пустой строкой)

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:8090 A4Tech Co., Ltd. X-718BK Oscar Optical Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 256c:006d  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Хотелось бы настроить четыре кнопки на планшете (повесить им функцию)

Comment: через `xev` или `evtest` нажатия на эти кнопки видны?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, через xev нет, через evtest видно

Comment: тогда в сторону настройки xorg'а копай... заодно посмотри, может что в его логах есть интересное... в статье по ссылке секции выглядели несколько странно — можно их снести попробовать или какую-нить аналогичную добавить...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, есть что-то почитать по настройке для планшета, чтобы сильно не углубляться в дебри?

Comment: не особо... только гугл с ключевыми словами (в порядке важности) «wacom X11 linux DIGImend HUOIN» в разных комбинациях... [в арчевике](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wacom_tablet#Configuration) вроде что-то в тему написано... [в README](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers) к дровам тоже что-то есть... подозрительно выглядит, что `xsetwacom` ничего не выводит — хотя, возможно, это просто описка: `list devices` должно быть без дефисов...

Comment: @Fat-Zer? разобрался, заработало. По даноной вами ссылочке.

Comment: нум... тогда можешь оформлять в ответ и закрывать — может кому-нить когда-нить пригодится...

Answer (score 0):

Делаем как написано в статье https://www.davidrevoy.com/article331/setup-huion-giano-wh1409-tablet-on-linux-mint-18-1-ubuntu-16-04

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers.git /usr/src/digimend-9
sudo dkms build digimend/9
sudo dkms install digimend/9
```

Затем вводим команду `lsusb` на выходе что-то типа

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 09da:8090 A4Tech Co., Ltd. X-718BK Oscar Optical Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 256c:006d  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

В моем случае планшет без имени и имеет `ID 256c:006d`

Редактируем /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/50-tablet.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Tablet"
    Driver "wacom"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    MatchUSBID "<VID>:<PID>"  // Это ID, которое узнали выше, у меня 256c:006d
EndSection
```

Для установки функциональных клавиш, можно воспользоваться коммандой

```
xsetwacom --set "$tabletpad" Button 2 "key Shift_L" # resize brush
# Ну и так для всех клавиш
```

Но эти установки клавиш действуют до перезагрузки системы, можно создать простенький БАШ-скрипт и кинуть его в автозагрузку. Дополнительная информация на  [сайте ДИДЖИМЕДа](https://github.com/DIGImend/digimend-kernel-drivers)